# How often will client hit the vercel server if middleware, getStaticProps and getInitialProps(_app.tsx) are present

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-rewrites

How often will client hit the nextjs server if I add the node-cache npm package in app's middleware which uses rewrites and all my pages have getStaticProps along with getStaticPaths and middleware run for all the pages also app's _app.ts file have getInitialProps function attached to App ?

I need to cache the data, is it a good idea to cache the data on vercel server for above use-case or should I use redis?